# What is [sql-match-all]?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki

I am looking for some guidance on how to use [sql-match-all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-match-all) tag and what is its purpose. There is no tag wiki or excerpt. What is the purpose of this tag?

The only helpful information I found is in [an answer by Bill Karwin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8684729/1839439):

> Regarding matching multiple facilities when they're stored on separate rows, I've added the sql-match-all tag which is used on Stack Overflow for that type of problem. It comes up frequently, and there are lots of good answers already. Click the tag to find them.

Comment: sql-match-all is the weekly TV show where we try to make the best RDBMS from several contenders. Tune in to see Oracle, MS-SQL, Maria, MySql, Postgresql to match them all. Or will there be an unexpected outsider to snatch the win? This Saturday 03:00 UTC on SO-TV.

Comment: It was created in 2011, and the creator seems to add it to questions it answers, so there's that. I don't see anyone else adding this tag.

Comment: I'm wondering whether it's more or less cases of relational division (there is a tag), returning rows with values that match all of some other values. (The latter given in SQL via table or literals.) [check if a column contains ALL the values of another column - Mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28939367/3404097)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's logically the same as [relational-division](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/relational-division) but most developers don't know what relational division means. And there are tricks to perform a "match all" operation in some cases that are not implemented using relational division techniques.

It was my attempt to create a tag that uses lay person's language. When I created it in 2011, I didn't know that tags could be created as synonyms for other tags.

So I'd make this a synonym for [relational-division](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/relational-division) if anything.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem that this describes anything particular to SQL, it's more of a "fetch all the things" tag from what I can see (which is what SQL does normally?). It's 9 years old and has only 51 questions. Honestly, I would suggest we synonym it to [sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql), since I can't seem to find any reason to have this tag.

That having been said, it was created by a [very high reputation user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20860/bill-karwin) who is still active. If you could ping him, maybe we can get a reason to keep it. I suspect it was just a tag made back in looser tagging rule days.